# Best practice to get a list of objects from view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have one class like

```
public class Questions
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string questionText { get; set; }
    public int questionType { get; set; }
}
```

Now when various questions are created in the view and submitted, what should be the controller's action code and how should I design my view so that I can get the list of questions with all the properties set directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Model binding to `IList<T>`

I've written about model binding to `IList<T>`. I think this is exactly the problem that you're trying to solve. And there are some more posts on my blog that may help you lots especially because you didn't say whether you're having an HTML form of questions or Javascript objects built by some generic question form. Anyway. These two posts will help you address both problems:

- [Asp.net MVC model binding to `IList<T>`](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html)
- [Sending complex JSON objects to Asp.net MVC using jQuery Ajax](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html)

By understanding Asp.net MVC model binding you will be able to easily bind your client-side data (forms or objects) to:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestions(IList<Question> questions)
{
    // process questions
}
```

### Suppose you're posting back an HTML form

The main requirement is that you index your HTML field names correctly, because names are those that get posted back to server. In your case your fields should be:

```
<input type="text" value="questions[0].questionText" />
<select name="question[0].questionType">
    <!-- options -->
</select>
```

When you dynamically add new pairs (to form new questions) you have to make sure:

1. item indexing starts with 0 and
2. there are no gaps in indexes.

If you also provide the ability to remove certain questions (while adding/editing them), you will have to reindex items on each removal.

### Model validation (forms or correctly prepared objects)

The great thing about doing it this way is that you can put data annotations attributes to your application model class and get your posted objects automatically validated, so you don't have to do this yourself.